# Unable to receive authorization code from response with OpenIDConnects

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, microsoft-graph-api, openid-connect

I am trying to get the authorization code which is the response from open ID connect to call Microsoft Graph API.

This is my code

appsettings.json

```
"AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "TenantId": "common",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc",
    "ClientId": "my-client-id",
    "ClientSecret": "my-client-secret",

  },
  "DownstreamApi": {
    "BaseUrl": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0",
    "Scopes": "user.read presence.read mailboxsettings.read mail.read"
  },
```

Program.cs file

```
services
.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    //options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    //options.DefaultChallengeScheme = GoogleDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultScheme = "AppCookie";
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "MyAzureAdScheme";
    //options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;

})
.AddCookie("AppCookie")
.AddGoogle(GoogleDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, googleOptions =>
{
    googleOptions.ClientId = builder.Configuration["Authentication:Google:ClientId"];
    googleOptions.ClientSecret = builder.Configuration["Authentication:Google:ClientSecret"];
    googleOptions.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey("urn:google:picture", "picture", "url");

    // Add the required scope for GMail API access
    googleOptions.Scope.Add("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly");
    googleOptions.SaveTokens = true;

})
.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"))
.EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(initialScopes)
.AddMicrosoftGraph(configuration.GetSection("DownstreamApi"))
.AddInMemoryTokenCaches();
```

In the above code, I'm trying to add services for microsoft graph (not sureif it is correct). and google log in. The google part works just fine.
Then, in my controller, I am authenticating the user with OpenIDConnect scheme.

Controller

Here, I'm trying to do the authentication and it will redirect me to the microsoft call back.

```
  public async Task MicrosoftLogin()
        {
            await HttpContext.ChallengeAsync(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, new AuthenticationProperties
            {
                RedirectUri = Url.Action("MicrosoftCallback")
            });
        }
```

Then, at the call back below, I'm trying to get the authorization code and call the Microsoft Graph API.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> MicrosoftCallback()
        {
            var authResult = await HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
            var authCode = HttpContext.Request.Query["code"];
         
        }
```

I am not able to see the authCode.

I've tried to look at my url, then I found another issue which is tricky in the microsoft sign in page :

```
response_type=code
response_mode=form_post
```

I've read the resources online and it says that when the response_type is code, the mode should be query instead of form_post